# Как составить цикл и формулу в этой задаче? И как связать вычисление суммы с переменными из двух массивов?

Tags: массивы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как составить цикл и формулу в этой задаче? И как связать вычисление суммы с переменными из двух массивов?

Comment: Так и в чем проблема? Что именно у Вас не получается?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
c = 0;
for i in range(len(A)):
    if (abs(A[i]) >= abs(2*B[i])) and (B[i] != 0):
        c = c + pow(A[i]/B[i], 2)
if (c == 0):
    print("Элементов не найдено")
else:
    print(c)
```

`len(A)` - размер массива;

Функция `abs` - возвращает модуль числа;

Функция `pow` - возводит в степень.